# Convertir candena numerica en lista de int en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Cordial saludo compañeros,

Tengo la siguiente variable esta es varchar, por que de esta forma me llegan los dato de una aplicación SET @checkDia = '1,4,5,6,7' lo que quiero es que en un procedimiento almacenado dentro de un query como el siguiente pueda reemplazar en el "in" con estos datos de @checkDia para ello creo que se deben convertir a INT y separar por filas, no se si estoy en lo correcto y no se como realizarlo,  el query es el siguiente:

```
select id AS '#', fecha, 0 AS ESTADO
     from FECHAS
     where datepart(dw, fecha) IN(1,2,3) //aqui va el @checkDia
     OPTION
     (MaxRecursion 0)
```

e intentado separarlo con STRING_SPLIT pero no encuentro la forma de realizarlo

```
select value 
from STRING_SPLIT(@checkDia, ',')
```

Agradeceria si me pueden colaborar indicandome como debo realizarlo o si no es necesario realizar la conversión y por contrario puedo dentro del in enviar el texto que no creo se pueda.

Muchas gracias y quedo atento

Comment: ¿Por qué tienes el MAXRECURSION?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solo tienes que tener la consulta que usa `STRING_SPLIT()` dentro del `IN()`.

```
SELECT id AS '#', 
       fecha, 
       0 AS ESTADO
FROM FECHAS
WHERE DATEPART(dw, fecha) IN(SELECT [value] 
                            FROM STRING_SPLIT(@checkDia, ','));
```